# how to give the column names dynamically in kendoGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI grid.I want to display column names dynamically.can you tell me how to display columns dynamically

```
                   var columns = [];
                       columns.push({ field: "prj_project_time_entry_start_date", title: "period" });
                       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                           var entryIndex = "entries[" + i + "]";
                           columns.push({
                               field: entryIndex,
                               title: "" + json[i].usr_bio_first_name
                           });
                       }
                     var configuration = {
                           editable: true,
                           sortable: true,
                           scrollable: false,
                           columns: columns
                       };

                       var timeGrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid(configuration).data("kendoGrid");
```

This is how I am able to display columns dynamically.For displaying the records in the grid I used like

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({                                                                                       dataSource: gridDataSource,
              selectable: "multiple",
              sortable: false,
              refresh: true,
              navigatable: false
   });
```

If i give like this,all the values in my controller(query) are displaying with out depending upon the column names.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by display column names dynamically?

Basically to bind to a collection of dynamic objects, you can use the approach in [this code library project](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid.aspx). If you want to change the name of the column, you should use the Title method (which accepts a string as parameter).

```
columns.Bound("ProductID").Title("Column name Here");
```